# Python: Find ORDER_ID for eactly 2 PROD_ID

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below python list of list. I need to find out order_ids where only P1 and P2 (both but no other than P1 and P2) products are ordered. Expected answer: 5 and 9

```
# ORDER_ID, PROD_ID, ORDER_DT, QUANTITY

orders = [
[9, 'P1', '2020-01-01', 1],
[9, 'P2', '2020-01-01', 1],
[6, 'P1', '2020-01-01', 1],
[6, 'P3', '2020-01-01', 1],
[6, 'P4', '2020-01-01', 1],
[7, 'P1', '2020-01-01', 1],
[7, 'P2', '2020-01-01', 1],
[7, 'P3', '2020-01-01', 1],
[5, 'P2', '2020-01-01', 1],
[5, 'P1', '2020-01-01', 1]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `pandas` - it's way better for this kind of tasks:

```py
import pandas as pd

orders = [
[9, 'P1', '2020-01-01', 1],
[9, 'P2', '2020-01-01', 1],
[6, 'P1', '2020-01-01', 1],
[6, 'P3', '2020-01-01', 1],
[6, 'P4', '2020-01-01', 1],
[7, 'P1', '2020-01-01', 1],
[7, 'P2', '2020-01-01', 1],
[7, 'P3', '2020-01-01', 1],
[5, 'P2', '2020-01-01', 1],
[5, 'P1', '2020-01-01', 1]
]

cols="ORDER_ID,PROD_ID,ORDER_DT,QUANTITY".split(",")

df=pd.DataFrame(orders, columns=cols)

res=df.groupby("ORDER_ID")["PROD_ID"].agg(set).eq({'P1', 'P2'})
res=res.loc[res].index

res=df.loc[df["ORDER_ID"].isin(res)]
print(res)

#if you want end up with the numpy:

print(res.to_numpy())

#to get just the order_id-s:

print(res["ORDER_ID"].unique())
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> print(res)

   ORDER_ID PROD_ID    ORDER_DT  QUANTITY
0         9      P1  2020-01-01         1
1         9      P2  2020-01-01         1
8         5      P2  2020-01-01         1
9         5      P1  2020-01-01         1

>>> print(res.to_numpy())

[[9 'P1' '2020-01-01' 1]
 [9 'P2' '2020-01-01' 1]
 [5 'P2' '2020-01-01' 1]
 [5 'P1' '2020-01-01' 1]]

>>> print(res["ORDER_ID"].unique())

[9 5]
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :) , in such case - please mark it as an answer to close off this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). This way, you can group the products according to their order ID, and then have all relevant orders in a list. Then you just need to make sure that the product IDs match. Something like:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

products = []
for key, group in groupby(orders, key=itemgetter((0))):
    if {prod[1] for prod in group} == {'P1', 'P2'}:
        products.append(key)

print(products)
```

And this indeed gives:

```
[9, 5]
```

---

- this assumes the list of `orders` is sorted according to the Order ID, as in the example.